# How to align text in different viewports bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to align some text left on large, center on medium, right on small. But I can't get it to work.

I'm using vue-bootstrap.

```html
<div class="container">
    <b-row class="row">
      <b-col sm="4" class="my-auto text-lg-left text-md-center text-sm-center">
        <span class="text-white">
          2020 copyright, All rights reserved.
        </span>
      </b-col>
      <b-col sm="4" class="mt-2 text-center">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </b-col>
      <b-col sm="4" class="mt-2 text-right text-sm-center">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </div>
```

How do I align text on different viewports?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<p class="text-lg-left text-md-center text-sm-center"> 2020 copyright, All rights reserved. </p>
<quote>Bootstrap v4.3.1 is required, v4.5.3 is recommended</quote>
```

[bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

your classes should be inside the 'p' tag.

```
<p class="text-left">Left aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
<p class="text-right">Right aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>

<p class="text-sm-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized SM (small) or wider.</p>
<p class="text-md-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized MD (medium) or wider.</p>
<p class="text-lg-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized LG (large) or wider.</p>
<p class="text-xl-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized XL (extra-large) or wider.</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me:
            <p class="text-white text-lg-left text-md-center text-sm-center">
              2020 copyright, All rights reserved.
            </p>

Comment: why not working, see snippet. U need to include bootstrap

Comment: bootstrap is included.

Comment: can u remove text-white, it's making your text white. If it's not working for you then something wrong with your other stuff, not bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

To align the text in the order as you mentioned use:

```
<p class="text-right text-md-center text-lg-left">Something</p>
```

Comment: Please, add some detail on the suggestion, so the answer could be more useful. Explanation on the classes you use could be a great addition

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.